# firebase real-time database timestamp

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase in my application. I have two lists. Both of the data from the same table. But the first one only have 15 data and the second list have all the data. So I try to use the following query

This is the query for all the data :

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = references.child("sales");

mDatabase.orderByChild("timestamp").addChildEventListener(hotSellingEl);
```

Here is the query for 15 data :

```
mDatabase.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(15).addChildEventListener(hotSellingEl);
```

Both above query returning different set of data. What could be the issue here?

Comment: `Both above quer returing different set of data.` please elaborate.

Comment: Both above query returning list in different order.

Comment: So the data is current, but it is out of order?

Comment: Yes. The order is wrong.

Comment: you are querying on the same data in your code, but in the second query you are retrieving the last 15

Comment: There is no difference in the order in which those two queries return the data. Can you edit your question to include: 1) a minimal implementation of your listener that shows how you process the data. A good way to show that minimally is typically by printing the results, and showing the output. 2) a snippet of the JSON you are querying, as text, no screenshots. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).